# Any way to access Google Drive presentation through HTTP? (Not HTTPS)

Tags: google-slides

It seems that Google presentations can no longer be accessed through HTTP, only through HTTPS. Unfortunately, I need to run a presentation on a custom hardware/software combination which only understands HTTP. Is there a way to use an HTTP URL to view the presentation? Or a simple way to tunnel it somehow through HTTP?

[Another similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25504/http-webproxy-to-access-clean-https-urls).

EDIT: In the end, I went with the alternative which doesn't use HTTPS, [SlideRocket](http://www.sliderocket.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it right, you are talking about Publishing a Google Presentation, which generates an HTTPS link. Unfortunately, there is no direct way to access it through HTTP. 
However, you could download your presentation and share it through another file sharing site.